# How do I calculate percentages with decimals in SQL?

Tags: sql, decimal, sum

How can i convert this to a decimal in SQL? Below is the equation and i get the answer as 78 (integer) but the real answer is 78.6 (with a decimal) so i need to show this as otherwise the report won't tally up to 100%

```
(100 * [TotalVisit1]/[TotalVisits]) AS Visit1percent
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
convert(decimal(5,2),(100 * convert(float,[TotalVisit1])/convert(float,[TotalVisits]))) AS Visit1percent
```

Ugly, but it works.

Comment: Thanks this is the one ive gone with as it rounded up the number, the other answers all worked as well though thanks allot every one :)

Comment: I've found it better to convert to decimal than float.  Certain divisions work better with decimal, at least on Microsoft SQL server:
SELECT 5555/CAST(1000 AS float), CAST(5555/CAST(1000 AS float) AS numeric(5, 2)), 5555/CAST(1000 AS decimal), CAST(5555/CAST(1000 AS decimal) AS Numeric(5, 2))

Answer (score 26):

Try This:

```
(100.0 * [TotalVisit1]/[TotalVisits]) AS Visit1percent
```

Comment: Make sure you add formatting in your presentation layer to round that down to 1 or 2 decimal places. Otherwise, you're likely to run into things like 33.33333...

Answer (score 2):

```
CAST(ROUND([TotalVisit1]*100.0/[TotalVisits],2)as decimal(5,2)) as Percentage
```

Not ugly and work better and fast , enjoy it!

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me:

```
CAST((1.0 * SUM(ColumnA) /COUNT(ColumnB)) as decimal(5,2))
```

Hope it helps someone out there in the world.

Answer (score 1):

At least in MySQL (if it helps), if you want to use float numbers you had to use a type float field, not the regular int fields.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a decimal to the 100

```
(100.0 * [TotalVisit1]/[TotalVisits]) AS Visit1percent
```

this forces all processing to happen in floats... if you want the final output as text, and truncated for display to only one decimal place, use Str function

```
Str( 100.0 * [TotalVisit1]/[TotalVisits], 4, 1 ) AS Visit1percent
```

Comment: Like your str answer nice and neat looking :)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably overkill to do this, but you may wish to consider casting all values to floats to ensure accuracy at all phases.

```
(100.0 * ( [TotalVisit1]+0.0 )/([TotalVisits]+0.0) ) as Visit1percent
```

Note, you really need to put code in here for the case that TotalVisits == 0 or you will get a division by 0 answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT(ROUND(CAST(TotalVisit1 AS DECIMAL)/TotalVisits,1)) AS 'Visit1percent'
```

This will return a decimal and the ROUND will round it to one digit. So in your case you would get 76.6. If you don't want any digits change the 1 to 0 and if you want two digits change it to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, no round and str or Over(). i found this as a simpler way to do it.

```
cast((count(TotalVisit1) * 100.0) /TotalVisits as numeric(5,3))  as [Visit1percent]
```

You can change the number of decimal points as you wish to

> e.g. numeric(5,2) or numeric(5,4)

Answer (score -1):

This might not address you issue directly, but when you round a set of numbers for display you're never guaranteed to get numbers that add to 100 unless you take special precautions. For example, rounding 33.33333, 33.33333 and 33.33333 is going to leave you one short on the sum, so the logical thing to do is to modify the percentage for the largest value in the set to take account of any difference.

Here's a way of doing that in Oracle SQL using analytic functions and a subquery factoring (WITH) clause to generate sample data.

```
with data as (select 25 num from dual union all
              select 25     from dual union all
              select 25     from dual)
select num, 
case
   when rnk = 1
   then 100 - sum(pct) over (order by rnk desc
                             rows between unbounded preceding
                                      and         1 preceding)
   else pct
end pct
from
   (
   select num,
          round(100*ratio_to_report(num) over ()) pct,
          row_number() over (order by num desc) rnk
   from data
   )
/


NUM                    PCT                    
---------------------- ---------------------- 
25                     33                    
25                     33                     
25                     34
```

Comment: This is a bad idea in general.  If the numbers don't add to 100 due to rounding, then that's how it is.  Monkeying around with them is just going to give less accurate results.

Comment: It's neither a good nor a bad idea, and generalities don't come into it. It's just a technique for achieving a specific hypothetical requirement.

Comment: True, but it's a bad requirement.  It leads to incorrectly displayed data.  And it doesn't answer the question that was posed above.  And it's not the most accurate solution to making the percents add to 100 either, though it may be the simplest.

Answer (score -1):

In ms Access You can use the SQL function ROUND(number, number of decimals), It will round the number to the given number of decimals:

**ROUND((100 * [TotalVisit1]/[TotalVisits]),1) AS Visit1percent**